# IF ELSE based on Todays date append rows to monthly Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a Google Apps Script for a Spreadsheet of mine. It is supposed to run a function and based on today's date return the results to a specific sheet in the spreadsheet. When just appending rows to the active sheet and not a specific sheet it works fine. Also, the code saves fine in the Script Editor, so I would assume there are no major errors. Perhaps I have it laid out wrong in the Javascript or a fundamental error in the code that I do not understand. I am leaning towards my IF ELSE or how I am setting the active spreadsheet then sheet, but don't know for sure. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the code basics:

```
function CheckDateInsertData() {
   function infoDate(){ this gets today's date}
 if (infoDate() >= 2016/01/01 && infoDate() <= 2016/01/31) {
   function GetData1{
      //this retrieves necessary data, working when not using IF ELSE statements and only single active sheet, without calling sheet by name.
      var Data =.......... ;
      appendData(Data);
      function appendData(Data){
         var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
         sheet.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName("January"));
         sheet.appendRow(['Date', 'Price', 'Location']);
         }
    }
} else if (infoDate() >= 2016/02/01 && infoDate() <= 2016/02/29){
    function GetData2{
       var Data = ........;
       appendData(Data);
       function appendData(Data){
          var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
          sheet.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName("February"));
          sheet.appendRow(['Date', 'Price', 'Location']);
          }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What datatype does `infoDate()` return? `2016/01/01` is arithmetic division, it's not a `Date` object or a string representation of a date.

Comment: It looks like you've got functions inside of other functions.  I wouldn't structure the code like that.  You *can* put functions inside of objects, and put objects inside of other objects.  I guess it's possible to have functions inside of other functions, and have them run.  You said that the code is working.  Why are you nesting functions inside of other functions?

Comment: Ahh you are right. It is returned as a string. So if I get rid of the function infoDate() and make it var todaysDate = new Date(); that would solve that part? Then how do I compare it to a manually inputted date in the IF statement?

Comment: Sandy Good - Can you recommend a better way to ensure each appendData(Data) returns to a separate sheet based on the date? appendData() is unique inside the function correct? Not sure what is considered best practice.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would lay out the code:

```
function CheckDateInsertData() {
  var todaysDate = infoDate();
  var startDate = new Date('2016/01/01');
  var endDate = new Date('2016/01/01');

  var startDateTwo = new Date('2016/02/01');
  var endDateTwo = new Date('2016/02/01');

  if (todaysDate >= startDate && todaysDate <= endDate) {
    GetData('1'); //Pass '1' as the argument
  } else if (todaysDate >= startDateTwo && todaysDate <= endDateTwo) {
    GetData('2');
  };
};

  function appendData(Data, oneOrTwo){
    var sheetToGet = oneOrTwo === '1'?"January":"February";//If, then, else
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    sheet.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName(sheetToGet));
    sheet.appendRow(['Date', 'Price', 'Location']);
  };

  function GetData(oneOrTwo) {//this retrieves necessary data
    var Data;

    if (oneOrTwo === '1') {
      Data = ['one'];
      appendData(Data, oneOrTwo);
    } else {
      Data = ['two'];
      appendData(Data, oneOrTwo);
    };
  };

  function infoDate() {
    return new Date();// this gets today's date
  };
```

I don't know if this will solve your issue, but hopefully it will give you some ideas.

Comment: I think I understand it. Let me try it and I will get back to you here.

Comment: So the sheet will always be January then? 
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    sheet.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName("January")); 
The old code works fine for appending rows to one sheet. When I added the setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName("name")); it stopped working.... Any thoughts on that?

Comment: See updated answer.  The code now dynamically changes the sheet name based on the parameter value passed to the function.  See the if-then-else statement with the `sheetToGet` variable.

Comment: It is strange that I can not get it to work with ELSE IF, I wonder do you know if the spreadsheet call is correct? 
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    sheet.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName(sheetToGet));
    sheet.appendRow(['Date', 'Price', 'Location']);

I can not get it to append anything anymore haha. Might have to go back to the drawing board. Thanks for the help!

Comment: For this situation, I'd use the debugger, and execute each line of code, one at a time, and view the values.  Click a line number on the left hand side.  A red dot will appear on the line number.  That's where the code will stop.  Don't click an empty line.  To the right of the bug icon, there is a drop down list of function names.  Choose the function name to debug.   Click the icon of the bug.